# i want to make random string from given information in python

Tags: python

like I got some idea to create Instagram user finder from name and last name
i know it will be not that accurate but i just want to create so

```
import random
first_name="abc"
last_name="xyz"
first_name_list=list(first_name)
last_name_list=list(last_name)
some_extra=[".","_","-","@"]
numbers = []
for i in range(10001):

    numbers.append(i)    



genuser=[]
genuser_len = len(genuser)
for i in range(genuser_len):
   
    user_name=genuser[l]
```

I want to create a bunch of username with this information
now I have no idea how to generate list
please help me

i want to generate usernames like this a_xyz123,  abc_xyz, abc.xyz, a.xyz023

Comment: You forgot a ```:``` after the ```for i in range(genuserlen)```. Also it should be ```genuser_len``` because you have defined that.

Comment: Seems like permutation and combination problem, you also need to define maximum number of characters for the username

Comment: @Don'tAccept so what should i do exactly

Comment: What you want to be the length of the username

Comment: not fixed depends on name

Comment: What I suggest is you get the length of the first name and last name: ```x=first_name+last_name```, then do: ```random.randint(x-2,x)``` and then it will select a random number between the range.

Comment: but problem is like username of name john cena can be c_john, cena.john, jon.cena008

Comment: Please read [ask] and ["why is 'can someone help me?' not an actual question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). You need to ask a *specific* question, which requires that you first *have* a specific question. We cannot *design* the code for you; you need to figure out the *what the exact problem is that needs solving* yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import random
first_name="abc"
last_name="xyz"
first_name_list=list(first_name)
first_name_list.append(first_name)

last_name_list=list(last_name)
last_name_list.append(last_name)
some_extra=[".","_","-","@"]
numbers = [i for i in range(10001)]
genuser=[]
genuser_len = len(genuser)
for i in numbers:
    list1=[]
    x=random.choice(first_name_list) #== Random choice from first_name_list
    y=random.choice(last_name_list) #== Random choice from last_name_list
    z=random.choice(some_extra) #== Random choice from some_extra 
    x1=random.randint(1,10001)
    list1.append(x)
    list1.append(y)
    list1.append(str(x1))
    random.shuffle(list1) #=== Shuffle list
    k=random.randint(1,2)
    list1.insert(k,z)
    print(''.join(list1))
```

Sample output:

```
abc120-xyz
4132@xa
c5336-y
8355_cy
abcz@3168
a-z9931
a.783x
9323x.c
x1980.c
z_3948a
```

Comment: so it will give all posibilities or in certain range

Comment: Yes it will give

Answer (score 1):

This is a permutations problem, and the output result is going to be enormously large for the given requirement, you can try something like this:

```py
from itertools import permutations

list(map(lambda x: ''.join(map(str,x)),permutations(first_name_list+last_name_list+some_extra+numbers, 3)))
```

**PS**: To avoid lage computational time and high memory usage for this example, I'm using range(11) for the `numbers` list, and I'm using `3` as the width of user names generated which is passed to permutations function above.

**SMALL SLICE OF OUTPUT**:

```py
['ab2', 'ab3', 'ab4', 'ab5', 'ab6', 'ab7', 'ab8', 'ab9', 'ab10', 'acb', 'acx', 'acy', 'acz', 'ac.', 'ac_', 'ac-', 'ac@', 'ac0', 'ac1', 'ac2']
```

Comment: sorry man i took time cuz as you said to avoid i didn't read taht and did it with 1000 numbers so  my laptop got stuck